# virtual method in exceptions

Tags: c++, exception

I have made my own exception class which derives from `runtime_error` and is getting an int in the c'tor.

I would like to make a base class for this exception, in order to use polymorphism, so I could catch only the base class and basically I would be catching the derived class, and then call .what() method from it.

So, this is the base class: (ofc in another cpp file I got baseException::~baseException(){})

```
class baseException
{
    virtual ~baseException()=0 {}
    virtual const char* what()=0;
};
```

And this is the derived class:

```
class myException: public runtime_error, public baseException
{
public:
    myException(int): runtime_error("Error occured") {}
    const char* what() {return runtime_error::what();}
};
```

But when in the main I write:

```
catch(baseException* x)
{
cout<<x->what();
}
```

it just skips it and does not enter the block, even though myException inherits from baseException. Any suggests?

Comment: What do you mean you can not?

Comment: Why not let `baseException` inherit from `std::runtime_error` and `myException` only from `baseException`?

Comment: Also, how do you use `throw` and `catch`? Please add that code to the question.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer: that's defined by `std::runtime_error` (assuming that's what the OP means by `runtime_error`).

Comment: edited so it would be clearer thanks guys!

Comment: Why do you need an extra base different to `std::exception`? Also, you should throw by value and catch by reference.

Comment: What exactly are you throwing? If you're throwing an object of type `myException`, then you'll need to catch a reference not a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your catching a reference to a `baseException` object; therefor you just know the methods of that class. `baseException` does not have a member called `what()` though. This causes the error.
Make `baseException` derive from `runtime_error` or catch a `myException` directly.

**Edit:**

This snippet shows that theres absolutely no reason why pointers shouldnt work together with exceptions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
public:
    virtual int test() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual int test() {
        return 42;
    }
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    try {
        throw new std::string("foo");
    } catch (std::string* ecx){
        std::cout << *ecx << std::endl;
    }

    try {
        throw new B();
    } catch (A* ecx) {
        std::cout << ecx->test() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

> foo
>
> 42

Comment: baseException inherits from runtime_error not an option, since each one of my derived custom exceptions sends a different message to runtime_error c'tor.

Comment: @Jjang: then pass that message in through the baseException constructor to runtime_error.

Comment: my answer contains an example of doing this

Comment: -1 because this answer is wrong. If it didn't have a method it wouldn't even compile. The problem is catching a pointer when it should be a reference.

Comment: @Jarryd At the time i wrote this answere the OP hasnt made his question more concrete. Besides that a quick test shows that its completely legal to throw pointers. Although your code will become exception unsafe. References are a better way due to the RAII pattern.

Comment: Throwing something allocated by `new` is a bad idea - the catcher must know both that he must catch a pointer (which is not what most people would expect), *and* that he must delete the object (which your code neglects). It also makes it impossible to `catch(...)` without a memory leak. You should throw by value and (if you want polymorphism) catch by reference.

Comment: @Mike Seymour "Although your code will become exception unsafe". Please read my answere and comments. Im aware of this and throw by value on my own. This is just about Proof-Of-Concept, because the statement "The problem is catching a pointer when it should be a reference" is definitely wrong in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

You should catch exceptions by reference (or const reference), not by pointer.

Comment: why? so how can I do polymorphysem if i catch by reference?

Comment: polymorphism is compatible with references, test it out

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - why?  It addresses exactly the original question.

Comment: So catching by reference fixes the problem?

Comment: At least one of the more obvious problems, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your `baseException` doesn't have the `what` method, you should probably just derive `baseException` from `runtime_error`.

```
class baseException : public runtime_error
{
public:
    baseException(const std::string& what) : runtime_error(what) {}
};
```

and then

```
class myException: public baseException
{
public:
    myException(int): baseException("Error occured") {}
};
```

Although I prefer the following idiom:

```
class myException: public baseException
{
public:
    myException(int x): baseException(getWhatMessage(x)) {}

private:
    static std::string getWhatMessage(int x) { /*generate the message*/ }
};
```

On the `catch` part. If you throw using `throw myException(5)`, then you should catch like this

```
catch(baseException& x)
{
    cout<<x.what();
}
```

Comment: but each one of the derived exceptions class has a different message and is getting different objects, some get ints some strings etc

Comment: so? add another `myException2` taking `double` as the argument, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: this answer was based on the original version of the question. It now seems that the problem isn't calling `what()` (as you've worked around that by redeclaring it in your base class). The problem is simply that you're trying to catch a pointer and (I guess) throwing a value; the solution is to catch by reference:

```
catch (myException const & ex) {
    std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
```

(assuming you fix your declaration of `what()` to be `const`; if for some reason you really need it to be non-`const`, then remove `const` from the `catch` line).

ORIGINAL ANSWER describing how to call `what()` if it isn't declared in `baseException`:

> I want to catch `baseException*`

You'd be better off catching `baseException const &`; there's no sensible way to throw a pointer.

> and call their `.what()` methods

If you want to call `what()` , then you might be better off catching `std::exception const &` instead; unless you also want some functionality from your base class. In that case, perhaps your base class should inherit from `std::runtime_error`; or perhaps it should inherit from `std::exception`, in which case your `myException` type would need to use virtual inheritance.

If you really want to access `what()` from your classes as they stand, then you'll need to cross-cast to `std::exception`:

```
catch (myException const & ex) {
    std::cerr << dynamic_cast<std::exception const &>(ex).what() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: why go after the begginer into this multiple inheritance madness and not just point the right way to do it?

Comment: @unkulunkulu: Because I don't know exactly what the OP is trying to achieve, and so I don't know what the "right" way is. One of the options I gave is to use single inheritance, but I don't know whether that will meet his needs so I also described other options.